# How do I access layout_height from within my custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, custom-view

I have a custom view and I simply wish to access the xml layout value of `layout_height`.

I am presently getting that information and storing it during onMeasure, but that only happens when the view is first painted. My view is an XY plot and it needs to know its height as early as possible so it can start performing calculations.

The view is on the fourth page of a viewFlipper layout, so the user may not flip to it for a while, but when they do flip to it, I would like the view to already contain data, which requires that I have the height to make the calculations.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From   **public View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)** constructor docs:

> Constructor that is called when
>   inflating a view from XML. This is
>   called when a view is being
>   constructed from an XML file,
>   supplying attributes that were
>   specified in the XML file.

So to achieve what you need, provide a constructor to your custom view that takes Attributes as a parameter, i.e.:

```
public CustomView(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    String height = attrs.getAttributeValue("android", "layout_height");
    //further logic of your choice..
}
```

Comment: The namespace should be "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" (preceeded by http://), otherwise height will be null.

Answer (score 14):

that work :)... you need to change "android" for "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```
public CustomView(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    String height = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height");
    //further logic of your choice..
}
```

Comment: I tried attrs.getAttributeValue("android","layout_width") and it returned null. Then I tried your solution and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: But still, it returns null for me about layoutDirection attribute!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    int[] systemAttrs = {android.R.attr.layout_height};
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, systemAttrs);
    int height = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    a.recycle();
}
```

Comment: It's important to call `a.recycle();` after get the height.

Answer (score 5):

### • `Kotlin Version`

The answers which are written to this question do not completely cover the issue. Actually, they are completing each other. To sum up the answer, first we should check the `getAttributeValue` returning value, then if the `layout_height` defined as dimension values, retrieve it using `getDimensionPixelSize`:

```
val layoutHeight = attrs?.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height")
var height = 0
when {
    layoutHeight.equals(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toString()) -> 
        height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    layoutHeight.equals(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT.toString()) -> 
        height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    else -> context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, intArrayOf(android.R.attr.layout_height)).apply {
        height = getDimensionPixelSize(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        recycle()
    }
}

// Further to do something with `height`:
when (height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT -> {
        // defined as `MATCH_PARENT`
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT -> {
        // defined as `WRAP_CONTENT`
    }
    in 0 until Int.MAX_VALUE -> {
        // defined as dimension values (here in pixels)
    }
}
```