# How to get resolved `android:layout_width` (or height) tag values in a Custom View

Tags: android, layout, android-custom-view, custom-view, android-attributes

First of all, related questions to my topic:

[How do I access layout_height from within my custom view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542456/how-do-i-access-layout-height-from-within-my-custom-view)

[How do you get "android:" tag values in a Custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877172/how-do-you-get-android-tag-values-in-a-custom-view).

So I have the result in a `String` which is ok, but **the question** is: is there a way to somehow automatically parse the `String` result that I get back from `attrs.getAttributeValue()` or is there a solution to get it somehow in an already parsed format ( = get the value in pixels)? Like when you call `getDimensionPixelSize()`.

Because the returned `String` can have values like `?2130772036` (reference), `-2` (wrap_content), `122.0dip` (or in the worst case `122px`, `122mm`, etc...).

And I don't want to add `layout_height` to my custom `attrs.xml` if not necessary.

Comment: are you aware of `onMeasure` method?

Comment: I am, but the thing is that I want to have the height information before `onMeasure` is called. I have a custom function and when it is called, the layout is not rendered yet, but I already need the height to manipulate other views based on the height of this one. I might go with `getMeasuredHeight()` solution, but still, it would be nice to get the height nicely from the attributes.

Comment: Well, as an extra piece of information: my view is `GONE` when I call my custom function on it, so `onMeasure` is not yet called at that time.

Comment: if you want size in pixels this is the correct place, otherwise you will get things like -1 / -2 (for dims like match_parent / wrap_content)

Comment: Probably I have to go with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10134260/7138729

Comment: this is called **after** `onMeasure` / `onLayout` got called

Comment: Well, the point is to me to get the height **before displaying** it and to be able to measure it when I want it, not when user calls display. I just thought that at the time of `onMeasure` or `onLayout` there is no way back and if I call `setVisibility(GONE)` on these functions, then the view might blink for a moment and I definitely don't want that. However if the view does not blink and I can control when to measure height, than it is fine. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: so maybe you will find the direct call to `View#measure` helpful?